# Python inheritance - how to disable a function

Tags: python, inheritance, interface, private

In C++ you can disable a function in parent's class by declaring it as private in the child class. How can this be done in Python? I.E. How can I hide parent's function from child's public interface?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There really aren't any true "private" attributes or methods in Python.  One thing you can do is simply override the method you don't want in the subclass, and raise an exception:

```
>>> class Foo( object ):
...     def foo( self ):
...         print 'FOO!'
...         
>>> class Bar( Foo ):
...     def foo( self ):
...         raise AttributeError( "'Bar' object has no attribute 'foo'" )
...     
>>> b = Bar()
>>> b.foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<interactive input>", line 3, in foo
AttributeError: 'Bar' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

Comment: >There really aren't any true "private" attributes or methods in Python.
That is why I didn't ask how to make them private, but how to 'remove' them from the interface. Hope that the edited version is more accurate

Comment: I agree that NotImplementedError is probably the best one to use, but if you really wanted to match not having the inherited method at all, raise AttributeError instead (which is what you'd get if the parent method didn't exist).

Comment: Good point regarding AttributeError.  I will update my example.

Comment: This doesn't do what you want -- an AttributeError will only be raised if the foo method is /invoked/ -- getattr(b, 'foo') still returns a method object (an attribute!).

Comment: @JBernardo, you shouldn't downvote an answer because it doesn't answer the question in the way you think best.  Nothing in the question indicates this answer is incorrect.  There can be more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: Python's documentation on `NotImplementedError` recommends just setting it to `None`: "It should not be used to indicate that an operator or method is not meant to be supported at all – in that case either leave the operator / method undefined or, if a subclass, set it to None."

Answer (score 20):

kurosch's method of solving the problem isn't quite correct, because you can still use `b.foo` without getting an `AttributeError`. If you don't invoke the function, no error occurs. Here are two ways that I can think to do this:

```
import doctest

class Foo(object):
    """
    >>> Foo().foo()
    foo
    """
    def foo(self): print 'foo'
    def fu(self): print 'fu'

class Bar(object):
    """
    >>> b = Bar()
    >>> b.foo()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    AttributeError
    >>> hasattr(b, 'foo')
    False
    >>> hasattr(b, 'fu')
    True
    """
    def __init__(self): self._wrapped = Foo()

    def __getattr__(self, attr_name):
        if attr_name == 'foo': raise AttributeError
        return getattr(self._wrapped, attr_name)

class Baz(Foo):
    """
    >>> b = Baz()
    >>> b.foo() # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    AttributeError...
    >>> hasattr(b, 'foo')
    False
    >>> hasattr(b, 'fu')
    True
    """
    foo = property()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doctest.testmod()
```

Bar uses the "wrap" pattern to restrict access to the wrapped object. [Martelli has a good talk](http://www.aleax.it/gdd_pydp.pdf) dealing with this. Baz uses [the property built-in](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property) to implement the descriptor protocol for the attribute to override.

Comment: Well, sure, in my answer it's still "visible", but you can't "use" it per se because it will raise the exception.  A valid point, though.

Comment: +1, what a smart trick to use an "empty" property to "delete" foo method! :D

Comment: This will break the class for the use of operators defined on parent because there's no subclassing. Also `__getattr__` is slow

Comment: What's the advantage of setting it to `property()` instead of anything else, such as `None`?

Answer (score 15):

A variation on the answer of kurosch:

```
class Foo( object ):
    def foo( self ):
        print 'FOO!'

class Bar( Foo ):
    @property
    def foo( self ):
        raise AttributeError( "'Bar' object has no attribute 'foo'" )

b = Bar()
b.foo
```

This raises an `AttributeError` on the property instead of when the method is called.

I would have suggested it in a comment but unfortunately do not have the reputation for it yet.

Comment: Will this raise AttributeError if you call `getattr(b, "Foo")`?  Unfotunately I don't have a Python Interpreter here to test it with.

Comment: if you mean `getattr(b, 'foo')` then yes it will

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.  Although `getattr(b, 'Foo')` will also give you an Attribute error, so no worries there!

Answer (score 5):

```
class X(object):
    def some_function(self):
        do_some_stuff()

class Y(object):
    some_function = None
```

This may lead to some nasty and hard to find exceptions being thrown though, so you might try this:

```
class X(object):
    def some_function(self):
        do_some_stuff()

class Y(object):
    def some_function(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("function some_function not implemented")
```

Answer (score 3):

That could be even simpler.

```
@property
def private(self):
    raise AttributeError

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def hello(self):
        print("Hello World")

class B(A):
    hello = private # that short, really
    def hi(self):
        A.hello(self)

obj = A()
obj.hello()
obj = B()
obj.hi() # works
obj.hello() # raises AttributeError
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the cleanest way I know to do it.

Override the methods and have each of the overridden methods call your disabledmethods() method. Like this:

```
class Deck(list):
...
@staticmethod
    def disabledmethods():
        raise Exception('Function Disabled')
    def pop(self): Deck.disabledmethods()
    def sort(self): Deck.disabledmethods()
    def reverse(self): Deck.disabledmethods()
    def __setitem__(self, loc, val): Deck.disabledmethods()
```

Comment: An interesting approach, but you need to make sure the argument number matches in case of pop, and keyword args are allowed for sort and reverse. Otherwise a TypeError will get thrown instead of intended exception.

Comment: Please, edit your answer for `@staticmethod` indentation

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is define an descriptor that errors on access.

```
    class NotHereDescriptor:
        def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
            raise AttributeError
    
    class Bar:
        foo = NotHereDescriptor()
```

This is similar in nature to the property approach a few people have used above. However it has the advantage that `hasattr(Bar, 'foo')` will return `False` as one would expect if the function really didn't exist. Which further reduces the chance of weird bugs. Although it does still show up in `dir(Bar)`.

If you are interested in what this is doing and why it works check out the descriptor section of the data model page https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors and the descriptor how to https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html