# How to use implementation inheritance?

Tags: python, inheritance, adapter, private-members

**How to use *implementation* inheritance in Python, that is to say public attributes `x` and protected attributes `_x` of the implementation inherited base classes becoming private attributes `__x` of the derived class?**

In other words, in the derived class:

- accessing the public attribute `x` or protected attribute `_x` should look up `x` or `_x` respectively like usual, except it should skip the implementation inherited base classes;
- accessing the private attribute `__x` should look up `__x` like usual, except it should look up `x` and `_x` instead of `__x` for the implementation inherited base classes.

In C++, *implementation* inheritance is achieved by using the `private` access specifier in the base class declarations of a derived class, while the more common *interface* inheritance is achieved by using the `public` access specifier:

```cpp
class A: public B, private C, private D, public E { /* class body */ };
```

For instance, implementation inheritance is needed to implement the *class* Adapter design pattern which relies on *class inheritance* (not to be confused with the *object* Adapter design pattern which relies on *object composition*) and consists in converting the interface of an `Adaptee` class into the interface of a `Target` abstract class by using an `Adapter` class that inherits both the *interface* of the `Target` abstract class and the *implementation* of the `Adaptee` class (cf. the [*Design Patterns*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) book by Erich Gamma *et al.*):

[image: Class adapter]

Here is a Python program specifying what is intended, based on the above class diagram:

```py
import abc

class Target(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def request(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class Adaptee:
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = "foo"
    def specific_request(self):
        return "bar"

class Adapter(Target, private(Adaptee)):
    def request(self):
        # Should access self.__state and Adaptee.specific_request(self)
        return self.__state + self.__specific_request()  

a = Adapter()

# Test 1: the implementation of Adaptee should be inherited
try:
    assert a.request() == "foobar"
except AttributeError:
    assert False

# Test 2: the interface of Adaptee should NOT be inherited
try:
    a.specific_request()
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    assert False
```

Comment: What's wrong with a.specific_request() being inherited? Do you expect it to be called by something?

Comment: Hi @MichaelYang. The point of the Adapter design pattern is actually to convert the `Adaptee` interface into the `Target` interface, not into the union of the two interfaces.

Comment: Like probably most OOP languages, if you want to express an "implemented in terms of" relationship in Python, you just use composition instead of inheritance. Python doesn't have any of the weird technical quirks of C++ that would motivate the use of private inheritance (or motivate the introduction of such a feature in the first place).

Comment: Do you actually insist on ``self.__specific_request``, or would you be fine with e.g. ``self._private.specific_request`` instead?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I have read the book *Design Patterns* so I am well aware that composition should be preferred over inheritance. But I want to implement it anyway as an exercise to better understand Python’s inheritance model. You should not discourage people from experimenting, you learn so much more.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I am okay with both, though I prefer the former.

Comment: Before delving too deep into metaprogramming: Is there a reason why setting ``request = Adaptee.specific_request`` in the body of ``Adapter`` is not sufficient for your use-case?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes MichaelYang’s first approach is simple and very close to composition (implementation inheritance is very close to composition; the only practical difference I see it that with composition you don’t access protected attributes). But it has two issues: 1. `Adapter` only hides `Adaptee`’s class attributes, not `Adaptee`’s instance attributes, since `Adaptee` can still assign public or protected attributes to `self`. 2. Contrary to `self.__specific_request`, `Adaptee.specific_request` only looks up `Adaptee`. This is fine for `Adapter` but not for an arbitrary base class list.

Comment: @Maggyero: Learning experiences are nice and all, but your question is posed as if it's actually a good idea, and you don't seem to have realized a lot of the flaws and limitations of the approaches you've come up with. A lot of it is going to interact very poorly with Python's MRO rules in a multiple inheritance scenario, which is extremely different from C++'s handling of multiple inheritance. Even in the case of single inheritance, your attribute name changes are going to wreck the ability of your superclass to find its own methods and instance attributes.

Comment: You almost never want to do this in C++, either. ***Strongly* prefer composition over inheritance**, even private inheritance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You don't want to do this**.  Python is not C++, nor is C++ Python. How classes are implemented is completely different and so will lead to different design patterns. You do **not** need to use the class adapter pattern in Python, nor do you want to.

The only *practical* way to implement the adapter pattern in Python is either by using composition, or by subclassing the Adaptee *without* hiding that you did so.

I say *practical* here because there are ways to *sort of* make it work, but this path would take a lot of work to implement and is likely to introduce hard to track down bugs, and would make debugging and code maintenance much, much harder. Forget about 'is it possible', you need to worry about 'why would anyone ever want to do this'.

I'll try to explain why.

I'll also tell you how the impractical approaches might work. I'm not actually going to implement these, because that's way too much work for no gain, and I simply don't want to spend any time on that.

But first we have to clear several misconceptions here. There are some very fundamental gaps in your understanding of Python and how it's model differs from the C++ model: how privacy is handled, and compilation and execution philosophies, so lets start with those:

### Privacy models

First of all, you can't apply C++'s privacy model to Python, because Python has **no encapsulation privacy**. At all. You need to let go of this idea, entirely.

Names starting with a single underscore are *not actually private*, not in the way C++ privacy works. Nor are they 'protected'. Using an underscore is *just a convention*, Python does not enforce access control. Any code can access any attribute on instances or classes, whatever naming convention was used. Instead, when you see a name that start with an underscore you can assume that the name is *not part of the conventions of a public interface*, that is, that these names can be changed without notice or consideration for backwards compatibility.

Quoting from the [Python tutorial section on the subject](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables):

> “Private” instance variables that cannot be accessed except from inside an object **don’t exist in Python**. However, there is a convention that is followed by most Python code: a name prefixed with an underscore (e.g. `_spam`) should be treated as a non-public part of the API (whether it is a function, a method or a data member). **It should be considered an implementation detail and subject to change without notice.**

It's a good convention, but not even something you can rely on, consistently. E.g. the [`collections.namedtuple()` class generator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) generates a class with 5 different methods and attributes that all start with an underscore but are all *meant* to be public, because the alternative would be to place arbitrary restrictions on what attribute names you can give the contained elements, and making it incredibly hard to add additional methods in future Python versions without breaking a lot of code.

Names starting with two underscores (and none at the end), are not private either, not in a class encapsulation sense such as the C++ model. They are [class-private names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers), these [names are re-written at compile time](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) to produce a per-class namespace, to avoid collisions.

In other words, they are used to avoid a problem very similar to the `namedtuple` issue described above: to remove limits on what names a subclass can use. If you ever need to design base classes for use in a framework, where subclasses should have the freedom to name methods and attributes without limit, that's where you use `__name` class-private names. The Python compiler will rewrite `__attribute_name` to `_ClassName__attribute_name` when used inside a `class` statement as well as in any functions that are being defined inside a `class` statement.

Note that C++ **doesn't use names to indicate privacy**. Instead, privacy is a property of each identifier, within a given namespace, as processed by the compiler. The compiler enforces access control; private names are not accessible and will lead to compilation errors.

Without a privacy model, your requirement where "public attributes `x` and protected attributes `_x` of the implementation inherited base classes becoming private attributes `__x` of the derived class" are **not attainable**.

### Compilation and execution models

#### C++

C++ compilation produces binary machine code aimed at execution directly by your CPU. If you want to extend a class from another project, you can only do so if you have access to *additional* information, in the form of header files, to describe what API is available. The compiler combines information in the header files with tables stored with the machine code and your source code to build more machine code; e.g. inheritance across library boundaries is handled through [virtualisation tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).

Effectively, there is very little left of the objects used to construct the program with. You generally don't create references to class or method or function objects, the compiler has taken those abstract ideas as inputs but the output produced is machine code that doesn't need most of those concepts to exist any more. Variables (state, local variables in methods, etc.) are stored either on the heap or on the stack, and the machine code accesses these locations directly.

Privacy is used to direct compiler optimisations, because the compiler can, at all times, know exactly what code can change what state. Privacy also makes virtualisation tables and inheritance from 3rd-party libraries practical, as only the public interface needs to be exposed. Privacy is an *efficiency measure*, primarily.

#### Python

Python, on the other hand, runs Python code using a dedicated *interpreter runtime*, itself a piece of machine code compiled from C code, which has a central *evaluation loop* that takes [Python-specific op-codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#python-bytecode-instructions) to execute your code. Python source code is compiled into bytecode roughly at the module and function levels, stored as a nested tree of objects.

These objects are fully introspectable, using a [common model of attributes, sequences and mappings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html). You can subclass classes without having to have access to additional header files.

In this model, a class is an object with references to base classes, as well as a mapping of attributes (which includes any functions which become bound methods through access on instances). Any code to be executed when a method is called on an instance is encapsulated in code objects attached to function objects stored in the class attribute mapping. The code objects are *already compiled to bytecode*, and interaction with other objects in the Python object model is through *runtime* lookups of references, with the attribute names used for those lookups stored as constants within the compiled bytecode if the source code used fixed names.

From the point of view of executing Python code, variables (state and local variables) live in dictionaries (the Python kind, ignoring the internal implementation as hash maps) or, for local variables in functions, in an array attached to the stack frame object. The Python interpreter translates access to these to access to values stored on the heap.

This makes Python slow, but also much more flexible *when executing*. You can not only introspect the object tree, most of the tree is writeable letting you replace objects at will and so change how the program behaves in nearly limitless ways. And again, there are *no privacy controls enforced*.

#### Why use class adapters in C++, and not in Python

My understanding is that experienced C++ coders will use a class adapter (using subclassing) over an object adapter (using composition), because they need to pass compiler-enforced type checks (they need to pass the instances to something that requires the `Target` class or a subclass thereof), *and* they need to have *fine control over object lifetimes and memory footprints*. So, rather than have to worry about the lifetime or memory footprint of an encapsulated instance when using composition, subclassing gives you more complete control over the instance lifetime of your adapter.

This is especially helpful when it might not be practical or even possible to alter the implementation of how the adaptee class would control instance lifetime. At the same time, you wouldn't want to deprive the compiler from optimisation opportunities offered by private and protected attribute access. A class that exposes both the Target and Adaptee interfaces offers fewer options for optimisation.

In Python *you almost never have to deal with such issues*. Python's object lifetime handling is straightforward, predictable and works the same for every object anyway. If lifetime management or memory footprints were to become an issue you'd probably already be moving the implementation to an extension language like C++ or C.

Next, most Python APIs do not require a specific class or subclass. They only care about the right *protocols*, that is, if the right methods and attributes are implemented. As long as your `Adapter` has the right methods and attributes, it'll do fine. See [*Duck Typing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing); if your adapter walks like a duck, and talks like a duck, it surely must *be* a duck. It doesn't matter if that same duck can also bark like a dog.

### The *practical* reasons why you don't do this in Python

Let's move to practicalities. We'll need to update your example `Adaptee` class to make it a bit more realistic:

```
class Adaptee:
    def __init__(self, arg_foo=42):
        self.state = "foo"
        self._bar = arg_foo % 17 + 2 * arg_foo

    def _ham_spam(self):
        if self._bar % 2 == 0:
            return f"ham: {self._bar:06d}"
        return f"spam: {self._bar:06d}"

    def specific_request(self):
        return self._ham_spam()
```

This object not only has a `state` attribute, it also has a `_bar` attribute and a private method `_ham_spam`.

Now, from here on out I'm going to ignore the fact that *your basic premise is flawed because there is no privacy model in Python*, and instead re-interpret your question as a request to rename the attributes.

For the above example that would become:

- `state` -> `__state`
- `_bar` -> `__bar`
- `_ham_spam` -> `__ham_spam`
- `specific_request` -> `__specific_request`

You now have a problem, because the *code in `_ham_spam` and `specific_request` has already been compiled*. The implementation for these methods expects to find `_bar` and `_ham_spam` attributes on the `self` object passed in when called. Those names are constants in their compiled bytecode:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(Adaptee._ham_spam)
  8           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              2 LOAD_ATTR                0 (_bar)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 BINARY_MODULO
# .. etc. remainder elided ..
```

The `LOAD_ATTR` opcode in the above Python bytecode disassembly excerpt will only work correctly if the local variable `self` has an attribute named `_bar`.

Note that `self` can be bound to an instance of `Adaptee` as well as of `Adapter`, something you'd have to take into account if you wanted to change how this code operates.

So, it is *not enough* to simply rename method and attribute names.

Overcoming this problem would require one of two approaches:

- *intercept **all** attribute access on both the class and instance levels* to translate between the two models.
- *rewriting the implementations of all methods*

Neither of these is a good idea. Certainly neither of them are going to be more efficient or practical, compared to creating a composition adapter.

### Impractical approach #1: rewrite all attribute access

Python *is* dynamic, and you could intercept all attribute access on both the class and the instance levels. You need both, because you have a mix of class attributes (`_ham_spam` and `specific_request`), and instance attributes (`state` and `_bar`).

- You can intercept instance-level attribute access by implementing all methods in the [*Customizing attribute access* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access) (you don't need `__getattr__` for this case). You'll have to be very careful, because you'll need access to various attributes of your instances while controlling access to those very attributes. You'll need to handle setting and deleting as well as getting. This lets you control most attribute access on instances of `Adapter()`.
- You would do the same at the class level by creating a [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses) for whatever class your `private()` adapter would return, and implementing the exact same hook methods for attribute access there. You'll have to take into account that your class can have multiple base classes, so you'd need to handle these as layered namespaces, using [their MRO ordering](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__mro__). Attribute interactions with the Adapter class (such as `Adapter._special_request` to introspect the inherited method from `Adaptee`) will be handled at this level.

Sounds easy enough, right? Except than the Python interpreter has many optimisations to ensure it isn't *completely* too slow for practical work. If you start intercepting *every* attribute access on instances, you will kill a lot of these optimisations (such as the [method call optimisations introduced in Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#optimizations)). Worse, Python [ignores the attribute access hooks for special method lookups](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup).

And you have now injected a translation layer, implemented in Python, invoked multiple times for every interaction with the object. This **will** be a performance bottleneck.

Last but not least, to do this in a *generic* way, where you can expect `private(Adaptee)` to work in most circumstances is hard. `Adaptee` could have other reasons to implement the same hooks. `Adapter` or a sibling class in the hierarchy could also be implementing the same hooks, and implement them in a way that means the `private(...)` version is simply bypassed.

Invasive all-out attribute interception is fragile and hard to get right.

### Impractical approach #2: rewriting the bytecode

This goes down the rabbit hole quite a bit further. If attribute rewriting isn't practical, how about rewriting the code of `Adaptee`?

Yes, you could, in principle, do this. There are tools available to directly rewrite bytecode, such as [`codetransformer`](https://pypi.org/project/codetransformer/). Or you could use the [`inspect.getsource()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource) to read the on-disk Python source code for a given function, then use the [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to rewrite all attribute and method access, then compile the resulting updated AST to bytecode. You'd have to do so for all methods in the `Adaptee` MRO, and produce a replacement class dynamically that'll achieve what you want.

This, again, is *not easy*. The `pytest` project does something like this, they [rewrite test assertions](http://pybites.blogspot.com/2011/07/behind-scenes-of-pytests-new-assertion.html) to provide much more detailed failure information than otherwise possible. This simple feature requires a [1000+ line module to achieve](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/src/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py), paired with a [1600-line test suite](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/testing/test_assertrewrite.py) to ensure that it does this correctly.

And what you've then achieved is bytecode that doesn't match the original source code, so anyone having to debug this code will have to deal with the fact that the source code the debugger sees doesn't match up with what Python is executing.

You'll also lose the dynamic connection with the original base class. Direct inheritance without code rewriting lets you dynamically update the `Adaptee` class, rewriting the code forces a disconnect.

### Other reason these approaches can't work

I've ignored a further issue that neither of the above approaches can solve. Because Python doesn't have a privacy model, there are plenty of projects out there where code interacts with class state *directly*.

E.g., what if your `Adaptee()` implementation relies on a utility function that will try to access `state` or `_bar` directly? It's part of the same library, the author of that library would be well within their rights to assume that accessing `Adaptee()._bar` is safe and normal. Neither attribute intercepting nor code rewriting will fix this issue.

I also ignored the fact that `isinstance(a, Adaptee)` will still return `True`, but if you have hidden it's public API by renaming, you have broken that contract. For better or worse, `Adapter` is a subclass of `Adaptee`.

### TLDR

So, in summary:

- Python has no privacy model. There is no point in trying to enforce one here.
- The practical reasons that necessitate the class adapter pattern in C++, don't exist in Python
- Neither dynamic attribute proxying nor code tranformation is going to be practical in this case and introduce more problems than are being solved here.

You should instead use composition, or just accept that your adapter is both a `Target` and an `Adaptee` and so use subclassing to implement the methods required by the new interface *without* hiding the adaptee interface:

```
class CompositionAdapter(Target):
    def __init__(self, adaptee):
        self._adaptee = adaptee

    def request(self):
        return self._adaptee.state + self._adaptee.specific_request()


class SubclassingAdapter(Target, Adaptee):
    def request(self):
        return self.state + self.specific_request()
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I expected, this is even better. Wow! Thank you a lot Martijn. You have completely addressed my question.

Comment: I have a few remarks if I may. I agree that in Python public, protected and private attributes are conventional *names* (including name mangling for private attributes), that there is no real *encapsulation* enforced by the language like in C++. When I used the terms in the question I was talking about names, I did not imply encapsulation. So yes, the goal was attribute renaming.

Comment: You said: "Python's object lifetime handling is straightforward, predictable and works the same for every object anyway." Yet I remember Bjarne Stroustrup or Herb Sutter saying that contrary to "native" languages (compiled to real machine code)—C, C++—, "managed" languages (compiled to virtual machine code)—Python, Java, C#—are not predictable since you never know when resources will be freed, it is at the garbage collector’s discretion.

Comment: You made an excellent point on the `_bar` and `_ham_spam`
 attributes in your section "The practical reasons why you don't do this in Python", I hadn’t thought of this. I was too focused on what the derived classes should see about their base classes and I totally overlooked what the base classes should see about themselves and their derived classes. Last morning I had finally arrived at a rather simple working implementation using attribute proxying that passed my test suite, but with this point you have just ruined it instantly.

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn't have a way of defining private members like you've described ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private)).

You could use [encapsulation instead of inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and call the method directly, as you noted in your comment. This would be my preferred approach, and it feels the most "pythonic".

```
class Adapter(Target):
    def request(self):
        return Adaptee.specific_request(self)
```

In general, Python's approach to classes is much more relaxed than what is found in C++. Python supports [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), so there is no requirement to subclass `Adaptee`, as long as the interface of `Target` is satisfied.

If you really want to use inheritance, you could override interfaces you don't want exposed to raise an `AttributeError`, and use the underscore convention to denote private members.

```
class Adaptee:
    def specific_request(self):
        return "foobar"
    
    # make "private" copy
    _specific_request = specific_request

class Adapter(Target, Adaptee):
    def request(self):
        # call "private" implementation
        return self._specific_request()
    
    def specific_request(self):
        raise AttributeError()
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231839/python-inheritance-how-to-disable-a-function) has more suggestions if you want alternatives for faking private methods.

If you *really* wanted true private methods, you could probably implement a metaclass that overrides [`object.__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__). But I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: instead of having a "private" copy, `Adapter` could call `super().specific_request()` in `request`. Advantage is that you don't have to modify `Adaptee`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes composition should be preferred over inheritance, but I tried to state explicitly that it was not the subject of my post. Your approach is interesting: you allow the inheritance of the implementation of `Adaptee` by making a private alias in it (not a copy technically) and you prevent the inheritance of the interface of `Adaptee` by overriding it to raise an `AttributeError` in `Adapter`. But the drawback of the latter strategy is that you also prevent `specific_request` to be looked up in other base classes that are not implementation inherited (though in this case there is none).

Comment: That is an astute remark @Jasmijn. However it assumes that you prevent the inheritance of the interface of `Adaptee` by overriding it to raise an `AttributeError` in `Adapter`, which prevents `specific_request` to be looked up in other base classes that are not implementation inherited (though in this case there is none).

Comment: To solve the issue that I raised, the following improvement can be made on your code @MichaelYang: remove the `specific_request` definition in `Adapter` and append this line at the end of `Adaptee`: `del specific_request`.

Comment: So far you have solved the first part of implementation inheritance, which is *class* attribute inheritance. There is also a second part to solve: *instance* attribute inheritance. With your current solution, `Adaptee` can still assign public or protected attributes to `self`.

Comment: @Maggyero: No, `Adaptee` can only assign regular attributes to `self`. There is no 'public', 'protected' or 'private' distinction. **Any** code can assign to instances, as long as they have an attribute dictionary (e.g. it was not created from a class that uses slots instead), that `Adaptee` can do this isn't anything special.

Comment: Why did you put the `_specific_request = specific_request` line on `class Adaptee:`? That could just as well be put on the `Adapter` class as `_specific_request = Adaptee.specific_request`. Not that any of this work, because the internal implementation of the `Adaptee` methods will, in general, expect `self` to still _be_ an `Adaptee` instance. Meaning that actual implementations of `special_request()` will try to access `self.state` and `self._other_attribute` and `self.some_method_or_other()`, and so will break because you replaced things in a subclass.

Comment: That's a fine suggestion. But I had imagined that `Adaptee` could call `_specific_request` internally. Either way, it makes little difference for the given example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for joining this discussion! When I said that "`Adaptee` can still assign public or protected attributes to `self`" I did not meant it was special, I meant the exact opposite: `Adaptee` should not have this regular ability. To achieve private inheritance, public (`x`) and protected (`_x`) attributes of `Adaptee` should be assigned as private attributes (`_Adapter__x`) of `Adapter`, while private (`_Adaptee__x`) attributes of `Adaptee` should still be assigned as is (since private attributes of a base class should never be accessed in a derived class).

Comment: @Maggyero see my answer. For that to happen you need full-on dynamic attribute translation, or code rewriting. That way madness lies. Moreover, that’s not the intended use-case of *class-private* attributes. Note that there is no concept, *at all*, of “protected” attributes in Python.

Comment: @Maggyero and note that in all these cases, in Python, Adapter IS-A Adaptee (a subclass), so altering the interface here violates the Liskov Substitution principle. I believe that the C++ technique specifically avoids the Adapter being classed as a subclass of Adaptee.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wow thanks a lot, I am going to read this! You are right, protected attributes are not part of the Python language (since they are not treated differently), they are just a convention in the Python community (they are treated differently by the developpers).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes it seems that in Python `Adapter` *has to* subclass `Adaptee`, but more for a technical reason (for allowing `super()` calls and the use of the MRO of `Adapter`) than a conceptual reason (Liskov substitution principle).

Comment: @Maggyero I think you are missing my point. C++ has made technical provisions specifically for this pattern because C++’s use cases (system development) include giving the developer fine-grained control over memory use. So it is only logical that the C++ model then also produces a class that logically is a subclass or Target _only_. Python has never needed this level of control.

Comment: @Maggyero basically, Design Patterns do not apply equally to all programming languages. This specific pattern does *not translate to Python*. But if you want to continue pursuing making this pattern somehow “work” in Python, then you need to be aware that you’d be doing so at the cost of breaking other OO principles such as the Liskov Substitution principle.