# How to create an identical class but with prefixed attributes in Python?

Tags: python, class, attributes, copy

I would like to write a function that takes an arbitrary class `A`, for example:

```py
class A(C, D, metaclass=E):
    x = 1
    def f(self): pass
    @classmethod
    def g(cls): pass
    @staticmethod
    def h(): pass
```

and that returns a new class `B` identical to `A` but with prefixed attributes, for example:

```py
class B(C, D, metaclass=E):
    prefix_x = A.x
    prefix_f = A.f
    prefix_g = A.g
    prefix_h = A.h
```

How can I do that?

Comment: since you're already using metaclasses, why not to do it this way? Another, less nice, option is to write custom `__getattr__`

Comment: How is this prefix going to be defined? is it some static prefix you will be adding?? Will the format be always prefix_attrName??

Comment: @ArunKalirajaBaskaran The prefix will be defined in the function or given as an argument, it doesn’t matter to me. Yes the format will be the same for all attributes.

Comment: @Marat Feel free to write an answer.

Comment: Can you add an example of the desired behavior then? It is not clear now if you want to pass an instance or a type, at instantiation or class definition

Comment: @Marat The function should take and return a class, not an instance. `A` is an input example, `B` an output example.

Comment: @Marat OP is saying "for instance" as "for example". They are not referring intances of the classes.

Comment: Do you need attributes renamed as well? Currently, there is only a class attribute ``x``, but nothing that is specific to the instance.

Comment: @Asocia Oh thanks for pointing this out, I did not realize that "for instance" might be confusing in this context! Updated.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Only class attributes (`x`, `f`, `g` and `h`in this example). For instance attributes I already have your `self` proxy solution.

Comment: This would be a a lot simpler if it weren't for arbitrary classes (which can literally be anything) and instead for classes intended to be used like this. Can you modify the source class definition, e.g. wrapping it in a function or treating it as a source code template? Otherwise, this is just a reformulation of your earlier question to clone a class.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have just found out an embarrassingly simple way to make `transform` work with `super()` without subclassing! Adding the `__class__ = cls` attribute when building the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trial and error, here is the result of the joint effort with @Maggyero:

```
def transform(cls, prefix='prefix_'):
     attrs = {key if key.startswith('__') else prefix+key: value 
              for key, value in cls.__dict__.items()}
     attrs['__class__'] = cls  # allow super() calls in methods of cls
     return cls.__class__(cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, attrs)
```

Comment: Thanks. A first improvement would be not to remove special methods, but this is trivial. Now a second improvement which is less trivial (to me at least, and which was the real motivation behind my post) would be to handle input classes `A` that use `super()` in their methods. For example replace `pass` in `A.f`’s body by `super().__init__()` and then execute `B = transform(A); B().prefix_f()`. You will get `TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`. Could you fix this?

Comment: @Maggyero check the update. I shouldn't have replaced bases in the metaclass

Comment: Thanks, you made `B` a subclass of `A` (that was also the only way that I found to support `super()`). I guess you meant the opposite: `key if key.startswith('__')` (without the `not`).

Comment: @Maggyero you're right about the `key.startwith`, fixed. The original plan was to make B  a "re-declaration" of `A`, but it didn't work. I am not sure if subclassing is the only solution, but it is definitely the easiest one

Comment: Thanks for the update. If you find a way to avoid subclassing that will be perfect.

Comment: it seems like there is no way to do it without subclassing. All `super()` will fail if the class is redeclared or instantiated manually because of an instance type check.

Comment: I have just found out an embarrassingly simple way to make `transform` work with `super()` without subclassing! Just add a `__class__ = cls` attribute when building the class.

Comment: @Maggyero wow, that is indeed embarrasingly simple

Comment: Your 1st function with the metaclass is equivalent to your 2nd function, right? So why don’t you just keep the 2nd one which is more elegant? (Because currently it is a bit confusing for the reader.)

Comment: @Maggyero updated the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for this fruitful collaboration Marat!

Comment: If you are interested, I have [another unresolved post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63106452/how-to-code-implementation-inheritance-in-python) which requires the technique we have used in this post (I actually opened this post for helping me solve the other one which is the main post). To draw attention on the main post I have opened a +50 reputation bounty which expires in 4 days. I am near the solution but not quite, and two brains are better than one, so if you interested by the intellectual challenge and getting +50 points of reputation, feel free to answer.