# How to ensure the child class can't access the parent's class method outside of the class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I have a class with some simple methods, and I want to create a sub-class of this which builds on these methods and adds some more functionality.

So, I inherit from this class, and build on the simple methods in the parent class in my child class.

Now, how do I ensure that you can't call the (simple) methods in the parent class from an instance of the child class from outside the class? I want the parent class to be used for the simple methods and the child class to be used for the more complex methods.

Comment: Don't use Python

Comment: Duplicate of [Python inheritance - how to disable a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231839/python-inheritance-how-to-disable-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

Python's philosophy is "we are all consenting adults". If a class has a method, then that method can be called on any object of that class, or of a child class of that class. Therefore, what you're asking isn't really possible.

There's still something you could do. If you had a method on the parent class, you could override that method on the child class and have it do nothing. In this way, creating an instance of the child class and calling one of the parent class methods will instead call the overridden method you wrote and not actually do anything. Yet, I'd consider the above bad practice; it's definitely not recommended.